# Save API response data daily without overwriting

Tags: ruby, rest, ruby-on-rails-4, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**UPDATED**

I have setup a model Graph with a single attribute, `:data`

I request, for eg, Facebook page and store the likes in data.

How can I schedule that API call everyday, such that two things are achievable
1. Value stored in `:data` is a hash of key - `updated_at` and value `:data`. This hash being added with value everyday without risk of overwriting.
2. All the `:data` stored everyday can be recalled in a page and presented like a monthly graph, or a calculation is done, for eg, to show avg likes per day, etc.

Controller

```
def index
    @fb = Graph.fb_page("facebook")
    @data = Graph.new(:fb => [@fb])
    @data.save
end
```

Comment: See [gems for scheduling](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/scheduling)

Comment: About the data saving part, I could easily use hash to do it. So please see the updated question.

Comment: what is the update? what specific info are you looking for? please show your attempt.

Comment: Idea is to add the api response in an array/hash everytime the api is  called. Preferably in a manner of key=datetime and value=likes, so that a question of, "Show the likes for each day of month" can be answered.

Comment: I guess that Graph.new line would overwrite everytime. What is the proper method

Comment: use persistent storage, i.e. a database